# Semantic UI / Meteor change default font

Tags: css, meteor, fonts, semantic-ui

I've got Semantic UI working just fine with my Meteor app (both latest versions), using SUI default theme. I only want to change the font from Lato to Roboto - just that and nothing else.

I've tried adding `@fontName: "Roboto"` to `/site/globals/site.variables.import.less` - still, everything comes up Lato.

The documentation is not very clear (to me at least!) so I further tried adding `@fontName: "Roboto"` to every single file that didn't start with DO NOT MODIFY - still, Lato everywhere.

Also tried adding `body {font-family: "roboto"}` in the SUI variables and `main.css` - still Lato.

I don't know what else I can try - SUI is so nice to use I thought something simple like changing font would be no trouble. Any ideas?

Comment: 'Using site.variables to modify page container sizes, default fonts, and colors', does that help? http://semantic-ui.com/usage/theming.html

Comment: @JanMellström unfortunately not - that's what I was following to get this far, but to no avail

Comment: Have you imported the font roboto in your CSS like: @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic&subset=latin');

Comment: @Sarthak No - that's what I thought changing the SUI fontName should be doing - it's currently downloading Lato but it should be downloading Roboto. I'm going to try it as you suggest, but that would be circumventing SUI, no?

Comment: did you manage to fix this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @JSmith Not even slightly. In the end I solved it by... giving up on SUI altogether and moving back to bootstrap

Comment: @rubie lol ok no worries... I'll persevere a while longer and update if I manage it.

Comment: Just adding `@fontName: 'Roboto';` to the `site.variables` file worked for me. I had to rebuild in order to recompile the less files after my change. In the network panel I now see a request for `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,400italic,700italic&subset=latin`

Answer (score 0):

SUI does indeed download Google Fonts for you. But you have to let SUI know which fonts you want in a particular manner.

This is an example from [here](http://learnsemantic.com/developing/customizing.html).

```
@headerFont        : 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
@pageFont          : 'Oswald', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
@googleFontFamily  : 'Open+Sans:400italic,400|Oswald:400,700';
```

You might just need to include the Google font you want in the `@googleFontFamily` variable along with the proper styles and weights

P.S. You'll have to add this in your `src/site/globals/site.variables`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is what changing the fontName variable should do - all the other headerFont/pageFont etc are controlled by fontName, as I understand it. I did however try setting it explicitly and still nothing - only Lato is downloaded, no Roboto :(

Comment: Bummer. adding the @googleFontFamily variable and re-building my SUI worked for me.